# Calculate the difference between two dates set using Bootstrap Datepicker in terms of Years, Months and Days

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have three `<input>` tags in my code out of which two are populated with dates chosen from **Bootstrap-Datepicker**.

```
<input id="from-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From">
<input id="to-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To">
<input id="total-count" class="form-control" placeholder="Total no. of Years, Months and Days.">
```

I would like to calculate the difference between these two dates in terms of **Years, Months and Days**, and display it in `total-count`. I went through some examples on Stack Overflow, wasn't able to achieve/find an ideal solution, because it was really confusing to me. If anyone could help me solve this, it would be of great help.

Below is my JS code. I've updated the whole code [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zNbUT/825/)

```
$(function() {

   // create the from date
   $('#from-date').datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
   }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
     ConfigureToDate();
   });


   $('#to-date').datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
     startDate: $('#from-date').val()
   });

   // Set the min date on page load
   ConfigureToDate();

   // Resets the min date of the return date
   function ConfigureToDate() {
      $('#to-date').val("").datepicker("update");
      $('#to-date').datepicker('setStartDate', $('#from-date').val());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with dates, there is no need to reinvent the wheel, **`Moment.js`** is a great library. (https://momentjs.com/)

Install/include the Moment.js on your page, then:

***HTML:***

```
<input id="from-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From">

<input id="to-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To">

<input id="total-count" class="form-control" placeholder="Total no. of Years, Months and Days.">
<br />
<br />
<input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" />
```

---

***JavaScript:***

```
$(function() {

  $('#from-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  });


  $('#to-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
  });

  $('#calculate').on('click', function() {

    var fromDate = moment($('#from-date').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    var toDate = moment($('#to-date').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY'); 

    if (fromDate.isValid() && toDate.isValid()) {

      var duration = moment.duration(toDate.diff(fromDate));

      $('#total-count').val( duration.years() + ' Year(s) ' + duration.months() + ' Month(s) ' + duration.days() + ' Day(s)');

    } else {
        alert('Invalid date(s).')    

    }

  });


});
```

---

***JSFiddle:*** (http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2u2bk/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Alex Baban ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this concept:

```
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

var days = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
var months = Math.floor(days / 31);
varyears = Math.floor(months / 12);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Usar . Learn't another way to find the difference between two dates! :)

Answer (score 0):

Working with dates I recommend you use a package like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), it helps you with the pain using some date formats.

```
var date1 = moment('01/05/2017')
var date2 = moment('01/04/2017')

date1.diff(date2, 'days') //1
date1.diff(date2, 'months')//0
date1.diff(date2, 'years')//0
```

If you want to get an exact difference, you could add the flag variable

```
date1.diff(date2, 'months', true)//0.03225806451612903
```

More docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Juan Caicedo . I've used Moment.js for my solution.

Comment: Remember to give +1, it is useful and helps the community to identify good answers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

  // create the from date
  $('#from-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    ConfigureToDate();
  });


  $('#to-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    startDate: $('#from-date').val()
  });

  // Set the min date on page load
  ConfigureToDate();

  // Resets the min date of the return date
  function ConfigureToDate() {
    $('#to-date').val("").datepicker("update");
    $('#to-date').datepicker('setStartDate', $('#from-date').val());
  }

  $("input[name='to_date']").on('change', function() {
    var fromDate = moment($('#from-date').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    var toDate = moment($('#to-date').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY');

    if (fromDate.isValid() && toDate.isValid()) {
      var duration = moment.duration(toDate.diff(fromDate));
      $('#difference').val(
        duration.years() + ' Year(s) ' + duration.months() + ' Month(s) ' + duration.days() + ' Day(s)'
      );
    }
  });



});
```

```css
input {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#difference {
  width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>


<input name="from_date" id="from-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From">
<input name="to_date" id="to-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To">
<input id="difference" class="form-control" placeholder="Total no. of Years, Months and Days.">
```

Just in case if anyone needs a code that Dynamically( without a click event) updates/calculates the difference between two dates.